# Creating a QuickLook plug-in for Blender 3.0 files in Xcode 13

Tags: preview, quicklook

I'm trying to create a QuickLook plugin to review Blender 3.0 files from Finder. This is an important feature of Blender in 2.8, but since Blender upgraded to 3.0 all previews are gone.
Due to I need to organize files and find files with QuickLook is pretty efficient and I'm not trying to give up. So after I read all the relative documents, I found they're pretty [out of date](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLProjectConfig.html), and not sure if any advice can help me to build one.

My attempts only display the default QL preview - a preview of the file.

Before:
I was using Blender 2.83, it can review files with preview.

[image]

Then:
I upgrade to Blender 3.0, and it cannot see any with preview.
[image]